# Genshi: for loop inserts line breaks

Tags: python, genshi

**Source code:** I have the following program.

```
import genshi
from genshi.template import MarkupTemplate

html = '''
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/">
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <py:for each="i in range(3)">
                <py:choose>
                    <del py:when="i == 1">
                        ${i}
                    </del>
                    <py:otherwise>
                        ${i}
                    </py:otherwise>
                </py:choose>
            </py:for>
        </body>
    </html>
'''

template = MarkupTemplate(html)
stream = template.generate()
html = stream.render('html')

print(html)
```

**Expected output:** the numbers are printed consecutively with no whitespace (and most critically no line-break) between them.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
            0<del>1</del>2
    </body>
</html>
```

**Actual output:** It outputs the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
            0
            <del>1</del>
            2
    </body>
</html>
```

**Question:** How do I eliminate the line-breaks?  I can deal with the leading whitespace by stripping it from the final HTML, but I don't know how to get rid of the line-breaks.  I need the contents of the for loop to be displayed as a single continuous "word" (e.g. `012` instead of `0 \n 1 \n 2`).

**What I've tried:**

- Reading the Genshi documentation.
- Searching StackOverflow
- Searching Google
- Using a `<?python ...code... ?>` code block.  This doesn't work since the carets in the `<del>` tags are escaped and displayed.

  ```
  <?python
      def numbers():
          n = ''
          for i in range(3):
              if i == 1:
                  n += '<del>{i}</del>'.format(i=i)
              else:
                  n += str(i)
          return n
  ?>
  ${numbers()}
  ```

  Produces `0&lt;del&gt;1&lt;/del&gt;2`
  I also tried this, but using `genshi.builder.Element('del')` instead.  The results are the same, and I was able to conclusively determine that the string returned by `numbers()` is being escaped after the return occurs.
- A bunch of other things that I can't recall at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but I did finally find an acceptable solution.  The trick is to put the closing caret for a given tag on the next line right before the next tag's opening caret.

```
<body>
    <py:for each="i in range(3)"
        ><py:choose
            ><del py:when="i == 1">${i}</del
            ><py:otherwise>${i}</py:otherwise
        ></py:choose
    </py:for>
</body>
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

If anyone has a better approach I'd love to hear it.